# Laravel / AJAX - Search Box and Search Last Name and Display it on Texbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can i search for last name and display the value in my textbox?

my problem now is when i type letter **D** the page hang and stop from loading it will hang.

image [image: Image Here]

as of now i have a ajax and jquery code so when i type a the first letter of my last name which is **D** then the input should have a value how can i do that?

my another question is, do you think my code in controller `<input>` and `output` is correct? or is it a invalid syntax? because im using `Form Collectives`

here is my code.

my ***Controller***

```
    public function search(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $output = "";
        $employees = DB::table('employeefms')->where('last_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                                             ->orWhere('firstname_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')->get();

        if($employees)
        {
            foreach($employees as $key => $employee){
                $output.='<input>'.$employee->employee_no.'</input>'.
                $output.='<input>'.$employee->last_name.'</input>'.
                $output.='<input>'.$employee->first_name.'</input>';
            }
            return  Response($output);
        }
    }
}
```

my Searchbox

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search">
```

my Form TextBox which i used the format of **Form Collectives**

```
 {{Form::text('last_name', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name'])}}
```

my ***Ajax Code***

```
$('#search').on('keyup',function(){
           $value=$(this).val();
           $.ajax({
                   type : 'get',
                   url  : '{{ URL::to('admin/employeemaintenance') }}',
                   data : {'search':$value},
                   success:function(data){
                           $('input').html(data);
                   }
           });
    })
```

my link of ajax

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

my ***FORM INPUTS***

here i make hide and show using javascript

```
  <div style="display:none" id="sectiontohide">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                {{Form::label('employee_no', 'Employee No.')}}
                {{Form::text('employee_no', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Employee No.'])}}
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                {{Form::label('last_name', 'Last Name')}}
                {{Form::text('last_name', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name'])}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                    {{Form::label('first_name', 'First Name')}}
                    {{Form::text('first_name', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'First Name'])}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                    {{Form::label('middle_name', 'Middle Name')}}
                    {{Form::text('middle_name', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Middle Name'])}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                    {{Form::label('nick_name', 'Nick Name')}}
                    {{Form::text('nick_name', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nick Name'])}}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

here is my ***Java Script***

```
   function toggle_div_fun(id) {

var divelement = document.getElementById(id);

if(divelement.style.display == 'none')
   divelement.style.display = 'block';
else
   divelement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: The page is crashing whenever Im typing on the search box :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing that:

1. typeahead.js is a package that was created just for this.

   https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/
2. change your JavaScript code to something like this:

   ```
   $('#search').on('change',function(){

       $value = $(this).val();
       $.ajax({
           type : 'get',
           url  : '{{ URL::to('admin/employeemaintenance') }}',
           data : {'search':$value},
           success:function(data){
               if (data.success) {
                   $('input').html(data.value);
               }
           }
       });
   })
   ```

I have made one change here; I made it on change instead of on keyup because the keyboard is not the only way that people enter things into inputs.

Also these changes to your PHP:

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $output = "";
    $employees = DB::table('employeefms')->where('last_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('firstname_name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
        ->get();

        $output = '';

        if(!empty($employees) || !blank($employees) ) {
            foreach($employees as $key => $employee){
                $output.='<input>'.$employee->employee_no.'</input>'.
                $output.='<input>'.$employee->last_name.'</input>'.
                $output.='<input>'.$employee->first_name.'</input>';
            }
        } else {

            return Response::json(['success' => false]);

       }

       return Response::json(['success' => true, 'value' => $output]);

}
```

Have a look at this for more info on Responses:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#json-responses

Comment: @SummerWinter that's enough. Josh has spent a lot of time helping you. Leave it at that. Ask another question about different issues.

Comment: Tip: Markdown supports code blocks and indented text inside ordered and unordered lists. For code blocks, use an eight-space indent instead of the usual four, and for text indent, two spaces works fine.